# Lightning component error for setTimeout: Bind must be called on a function

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We had following code in our component controller of a complex application-

```
window.setTimeout(helper.hideSpinner(component, helper), 500);
```

Functionality works but give an error as displayed at the bottom of the page:

> Bind must be called on a function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Resolution-

1. If set timeout modifies any attributes, use [`$A.callback`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm)-

   ```
    window.setTimeout(
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            helper.hideSpinner(component, helper)
        }), 
        500
    );
   ```
2. As per [setTimeout documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), use any one of the following if calling function doesn't modifies any attributes:

   ```
    window.setTimeout(
        function() { 
            helper.hideSpinner(component, helper)}, 
        500
    );        

    // or send function and arguments separately 
    window.setTimeout(
        helper.hideSpinner, 
        500, component, helper
    );
   ```

I searched on internet and didn't find any issues. We burned couple of hour to identify the cause because error message was not clear enough; at-least to us. Sharing it hereby in case some else is stuck with this problem.

Comment: The $A.getCallback method is required if hideSpinner modifies any attributes of the component, but if you're just toggling a CSS class, then $A.getCallback is not required.